# Can black pudding be stored long-term?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, sausages

A local restaurateur and friend of mine is making black puddings, and I am trading him a christmas pudding for one of his black puddings. I was considering saving it for a month or two.

Can I freeze it? Is it shelf stable like a hard sausage or bologna would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Black pudding freezes very well and should keep for a couple of months easily. It is not cured like salamis or other hard sausages, it's just boiled in the skin, so it does not keep as well at ambient temperatures.

When you do cook it, try it with pork tenderloin, mashed potato and fresh apple sauce. Just fry half-inch slices. Fantastic.